# How to password protect a twonky media server

Tags: qnap

I have a QNAP NAS TS 209 SII running a Twonky media server (Version 6). I've password protected the web server where the Administration's page is exposed. I Have also a Twonky media server running at the port 9000 which uses its own web server and NOT the apache one.

Does anybody know how to password protect the access to the Twonky?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to turn off port-forwarding for the Twonky port, and instead setting up a mod_proxy based reverse-proxy via the Apache server which is also running on the QNAP.

The [ApacheTutor](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies) site has a good [page](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies) on how to accomplish this:

But to summarise, ensure you have the mod_proxy modules loaded.  At a minimum:

```
LoadModule  proxy_module         modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule  proxy_http_module    modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule  proxy_html_module    modules/mod_proxy_html.so
```

And then set up the appropriate ProxyPass lines:

`ProxyPass       /twonky/  http://localhost:9000/`

Finally set up the appropriate lines to ensure access to this location is always password-protected.  This might be something along the lines of:

```
<Location /twonky>
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Twonky Restricted Access"
AuthUserFile /home/secure/apache.passwd
Require user twonkyuser
</Location>
```

This should expose twonky externally via http://your.external.address/twonky